# How do I specify which file I want to Post to my google cloud?

Tags: rest, http, google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud

I am new to cloud storage and simply want to post a textfile from my local machine to the google cloud. Right now it generates an empty textfile with the name I gave it.

POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/Bucket_Name/o?uploadType=media&name=testupload.txt
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN
Content-Type: text/plain

How do I specify the file it should upload under the name "testupload.txt"?

Comment: See Google's documentation [uploading object (using `curl`)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#prereq-rest)

Comment: You write code to read the file from the local file system. The Google Cloud Storage JSON API only specifies where to write the HTTP POST body data. Reading the data is the responsibility of your code. I recommend that you use the SDK instead of the JSON API.

Comment: You don't upload a file, you upload a content. Put the content in the body of your call. But, as @JohnHanley said, use the GCLOUD CLI or the client library to achieve that in a safer manner.